# Toggle CSS class on jQuery accordion Nav

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I know this questions has been asked more than it should be, and I have tried the answers that I have found with no luck.

I currently have an accordion style nav, with `+` beside each expandable section to indicate that it is expandable.

When I click on the category in my navigation I would like the `+` to disappear, and only reappear on that category once another category is clicked.

I have tried something like this:

```
$(this).toggleClass("accordion > li:before");
```

and like this:

```
$('.accordion li').toggleClass("accordion > li:before");
```

But have yet to get anything to work. You can see a working example below in my JSFiddle

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SimplyAzuma/Ww8WC/)

**jQuery that I currently have, minus what I've been trying to accomplish:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.accordion li').children('ul').slideUp('fast');
$('.accordion > li').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp('fast');
    $('> ul', this).slideDown('fast');
});
$('a').click(function () {
    $('a').removeClass("a-active");
    $('li').removeClass("li-active");
    $(this).addClass("a-active");
    $(this).parent('li').addClass("li-active");
});
});
```

Comment: pseudo-elements aren't selectable by JQuery because they aren't in the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mGcv8/2

**HTML** : Added a class to all your top level `<li>`

```
<li class="closed">
```

**CSS** : Modified your + content selector

```
.accordion > li.closed:before {
    color:#959699;
    content:"+";
    float:right;
    padding:14px 70px 0 0;
}
```

**JavaScript** : Modified your `li` click event

```
$('.accordion > li').click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('closed');
    $(this).siblings('li').addClass('closed').find('ul').slideUp('fast');
    $('> ul', this).slideDown('fast');
});
```

Comment: Actually, it broke another part of my site. It broke the part when you click on the sub menu items, previously it would add a bar to the side.

Comment: @MathewMacLean I don't see a bar in your original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SimplyAzuma/Ww8WC/

Comment: In my fiddle, click navigation, then click the "page 1" or "page 2" and look to the left. There is a small vertical green bar.

Comment: I somehow deleted that snipppet of CSS - fixed  http://jsfiddle.net/mGcv8/2 - Remember to accept the answer!

Comment: Wow, I even looked, how did I miss that too? Also that's awesome! Will be accepting as soon as I can! Thanks again.